# Computing derived tensor product of bimodules by resolving only one argument?

Tags: homological-algebra, tensor-products, projective-module, derived-functors

If $R$ is a ring, $M$ is a right $R$-module, and $N$ is a left $R$-module, the derived tensor product $M \otimes_R^{\mathbf{L}} N$ is computed by choosing projective resolutions $P_* \to M$ and $Q_* \to N$ and computing any of $M \otimes_R Q$, $P \otimes_R Q$, or $P \otimes_R N$.

I'm trying to understand the derived tensor product of *bimodules*. If $M$ is an $R$-$S$ bimodule and $N$ is an $S$-$T$ bimodule, then I can compute the derived tensor product $M \otimes_S^{\mathbf{L}} N$ by choosing projective resolutions $P_* \to M$ and $Q_* \to N$ and computing $P \otimes_S Q$. My question is: **is it sufficient to resolve just one of $M$ and $N$?**

The approach I want to take is to show that tensoring with a projective bimodule $P$ (or, more generally, a levelwise projective complex of bimodules) preserves quasi-isomorphisms. I can *almost* argue this: if $f$ is a quasi-isomorphism, then $\mathrm{cone}(f)$ is exact, so $\mathrm{cone}(P \otimes f) \cong P \otimes \mathrm{cone}(f)$ is exact since $P$ is (levelwise) projective, and thus $P \otimes f$ is a quasi-isomorphism. If I'm not mistaken, this works if everything is just a module over the same ring, but for bimodules there's an issue: $P$ being projective as a bimodule does not (to my knowledge) imply that $P$ is flat as a right module, and so I can't conclude that $P \otimes \mathrm{cone}(f)$ is exact.

I've looked over the proof of Theorem 2.7.2 in Weibel (balancing $\mathrm{Tor})$, and I believe it's very similar to my approach and has the same issue: it uses that tensoring with a projective module is exact. Am I wrong to be resolving $M$ and $N$ by projective bimodules instead of modules that are just projective on one side? My understanding is that derived tensor should be a functor out of the product of the derived categories of $R$-$S$ and $S$-$T$ bimodules; I compute derived functors by cofibrantly replacing the objects, and in the projective model structure on chain complexes, the cofibrant objects are the complexes which are levelwise projective (as bimodules).

Comment: You talk about bimodules but only compute the derived tensor product over $S$. If the resolutions $P\to M$ and $Q\to N$ are only of $S$-modules, then $P\otimes_S Q$ will not be an $(R,T)$-bimodule in any obvious way, so if what you want to compute is the derived functor of ${}_R\mathsf{Mod}_S \times {}_S\mathsf{Mod}_T$ to ${}_R\mathsf{Mod}_T$, you will have to consider resolutions that are at least in the correct category, and projective as $S$-modules.

Comment: I meant for $P$ to be a complex of projective $R$-$S$ bimodules, since that's what the cofibrant objects in ${}_R\textrm{Mod}_S$ are (and I do want to compute the derived functor of ${}_R\textrm{Mod}_S \times {}_S\textrm{Mod}_T \to {}_R\textrm{Mod}_T$). Similarly, I meant $Q$ to be a complex of projective $S$-$T$ bimodules. Are you suggesting that I can always find such a $P$ which is also projective as $S$-modules?

Comment: If you're working over a field, then anything that is $R\otimes S^{\rm{op}}$ projective is (right) $S$-projective: $R\otimes S^{\rm{op}}$ is free as a right $S$-module.

Comment: I see... I'm hoping to make sense of the derived tensor product for arbitrary rings though, not just algebras over a field.